# Algorithm for finding maximal "reduction" of an integer matrix

Tags: combinatorics, matrices, algorithms

Given a $m\times n$ matrix of non-negative integers. A "reduction" of this matrix can be done on one row/column of this matrix, by subtracting the minimum of the row/column from all other numbers of that row/column. For example,

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
 29 & 19 & 17 & 12 \\
    32 & 30 & 26 & 28 \\
    3  & 21 & 7  & 9  \\
    18 & 13 & 10 & 15
\end{bmatrix}
$$

can be "reduced" on the second row by subtracting 26 from all four numbers, resulting in

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
 29 & 19 & 17 & 12 \\
    6  & 4  & 0  & 2  \\
    3  & 21 & 7  & 9  \\
    18 & 13 & 10 & 15
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Such reduction can be repeatedly done on every row/column, and the result is always still a non-negative integer matrix. On the other hand, each row/column can be effectively reduced only **once**, because subsequent reductions end up subtracting 0 and do not change the matrix.

Hence, reduce each row and column once in any order, and the matrix is **completely reduced**. The question is: consider the sum of numbers in the final matrix, what is the minimum of this sum, among all possible **completely reduced** matrices? Further, how do we find out an ordering of reductions that achieves the minimum?

> The order of reduction does affect the sum of numbers in the final matrix. For the matrix above, reducing [row 1, row 2, row 3, row 4, col 2] gives a sum of 73, while reducing [col 1, col 2, col 3, col 4, row 1, row 2] gives a sum of 81.

---

I am interested in an (efficient) algorithm that solves this problem (or better still, if there exists a closed form of the minimum). One can always brute-force through all $(m+n)!$ ordering of reductions and find the minimum, but that would be quite uninteresting.

Comment: Do we need a maximal reduction each time we reduce a row or column, and can we reduce by a chosen amount ? The latter is polynomial, I don't know for the former.

Comment: In fact, I think that these problems are equivalent

Answer (score 2):

Lets first assume that we are allowed to reduce a row or column by a chosen amount, and not necessarily doing a full reduction.

Let $A =(a_{i,j})_{1\leq i \leq m, 1\leq j \leq n}$ be the matrix.
Let $x_i$ be the amount reduced in on the line $i$ and $y_i$ be the amount reduced in on the column $i$. We want to minimize $\sum_{i,j} a_{i,j} - x_i - y_j$, under the constraints $x, y \geq 0$, $x_i + x_j \leq a_{i,j}$. This is a linear program, so it can be solved efficiently. Moreover, the underlying matrix is totally unimodular, so we have strongly polynomial algorithm, and if $A$ is an integer matrix, we will get an integer optimal solution.

Let $G$ be the complete bipartite graph formed with $m$ vertices $X_i$ in one part and $n$ vertices $Y_i$ in the other part, and let $a_{i,j}$ be the weight of the edge $(X_i,Y_j)$. Then the problem becomes equivalent to find a vertex-weight function $x, y \geq 0$ (with $x_i$ the weight of vertex $X_i$, and $y_i$ the weight of vertex $Y_i$) such that $a_{i,j} \geq x_i + x_j$.
Shrijver[1] refers to it as the w-stable set problem.

Now, lets show that we can find on ordering of the rows and columns such that at each step, the reduction is maximal. Assume that $\forall i,j$, $a_{i,j} > x_i$, $a_{i,j} > y_j$. Then it is possible to increase any $x$ or $y$ and get a better solution. So lets choose an $a_{i,j}$ such $a_{i,j} = x_i$ (or $a_{i,j} = y_i)$, and lets reduce the corresponding row (or column). Let set $x_i = 0$, the coefficients must still form an optimal solution, so we can keep going until we reduced everything.

[1]: *Schrijver, Alexander*, Combinatorial optimization. Polyhedra and efficiency (3 volumes), Algorithms and Combinatorics 24. Berlin: Springer (ISBN 3-540-44389-4/hbk). xxxvii, 1881 p. (2003). [ZBL1041.90001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1041.90001).

Comment: A few issues: (1) I understand that $x_i$ and $y_j$ refers to the amount reduced on every number in the row/column, so the target function should be $\sum_{i,j} a_{i,j}-nx_i-my_j$. The linear program part still holds, very cool. (2) I don't quite get how the bipartite form of the problem helps in solving it. Do you only refer to it because that's how the book states and solves the problem?

Comment: $x_i$ and $y_j$ are in the inner sum. If you get them out, you get $n\sum_i x_i+m\sum_j y_j$. I referred to the graph interpretation because I believed it was insightful and its nice to have a name we can refer to the problem (though it does not seems to be wildly known, maybe this problem have another name)